# How can I generate a new Pandas column, comparing measures to the next Friday

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas `MultiIndex` like this:

```
                         Inj  time  
date       SID                                  
2016-10-11 ABC003S801    PBS    30        
           ABC003S802    PBS    12           
           ABC003S803    PBS    52         
           ABC003S804    PBS    19           
...
2016-10-12 ABC003S801    PBS    27           
           ABC003S802    PBS     5            
           ABC003S803    PBS    11             
           ABC003S804    PBS     7             
...
2016-10-14 ABC003S801    PBS    10           
           ABC003S802    PBS     3            
           ABC003S803    PBS     4            
           ABC003S804    PBS     5            
...
```

I'd like create a new column, which is the difference between an existing column (e.g. `time`) and the next Friday.

For example, the above data `2016-10-11` and `2016-10-12` should be compared against the next Friday `2016-10-14` -- **`df['new_column'] = df.time - df.time_next_friday`**:

```
                         Inj  time  new_column
date       SID                                  
2016-10-11 ABC003S801    PBS    30          20               
           ABC003S802    PBS    12           9 
           ABC003S803    PBS    52          48
           ABC003S804    PBS    19          14
...
2016-10-12 ABC003S801    PBS    27          17 
           ABC003S802    PBS     5           2
           ABC003S803    PBS    11           7
           ABC003S804    PBS     7           2 
...
2016-10-14 ABC003S801    PBS    10           0
           ABC003S802    PBS     3           0 
           ABC003S803    PBS     4           0 
           ABC003S804    PBS     5           0 
...
```

Note the difference should be between rows with corresponding `SID` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First swap date and SID index levels as it will be useful for backfilling later:

```
df = df.swaplevel().sort_index()
```

Fridays will be found by this boolean index:

```
fridays = df.index.get_level_values(1).dayofweek==4
```

So now you can perform the operation by aligning fridays data to each row by backfilling the values, and then perform the subtraction:

```
df['delta_vs_friday'] = df.time - df.time.where(fridays).bfill()
```

If needed swap the levels back.

Answer (score 0):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df` and index `tidx`

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=23, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(23) ** 2, tidx, ['A'])
```

Then the following is a dataframe of values for the next Friday

```
df.groupby(df.index.weekday.__eq__(5).cumsum()).transform('last')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that to work with my `MultiIndex`